# How to make a c#.net application portable

Tags: c#, .net, portable-executable

Im searching for a way to make my c#.net Application portable (or at least no installation needed). Some Background: I'm developing a small File-Manager for our Customers. As not every Employee of our Customer got Admin rights I need to hold it as easy as possible to use it.

My idea was to just deliver an .exe or Zip(containing .exe + dll of .net), that all Employees can use it by double clicking.

Is there any way to "bind" the dll to the exe?

Comment: That works out of the box, by placing the DLL next to the executable...

Comment: What do you mean by "bind"? If you build a .NET executable, it is deployed in the `bin` folder together with all the DLL files it needs, and will run wherever it is placed as long as those DLL files are next to it.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy it as a single binary without any DLL files?

Comment: Have you looked at ClickOnce -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: When you say dll of .NET you don't mean you're trying to include the framework in your package do you?

Comment: I would look at using group policy on active directly along with a MSI based installer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not just use ClickOnce deployment?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

No admin rights required... auto updating... what's not to like?

(Just deploying executables is a great way to eliminate your ability to update your clients... why do that?)

Comment: That whenever I have seen it used, it become a big pain for one reason or anther.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple .NET assemblies together using ILMerge: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

It's somewhat equivalent in concept to a static linker from C/C++ (except pretend that `.lib` files are directly executable).

Answer (score 0):

Try **ILMerge**,

ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17630

I also use this command line tool to merge several dlls and exe into single exe, use is very simple:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:destination.exe source.exe dll_1.dll dll_2.dll dll_3.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

In basic the program written in .net is 'portable' - you do not need to install it. (but the compatible .NET framework must be installed on client machine)

If you like to provide single assembly, you need to download and install the IlMerge utitlity (see Dai's answer) and then have either post-build command defined or I usually do a bat file with content like this:

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /target:winexe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0" /out:ALLINONE.exe PROGRAM.exe LIBRARY1.dll LIBRARY2.dll

Note, the paths depends on how it is on your system...

Also I recommend to '[obfuscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)' your assembly - you can use for example good opensource utility '[ConfuserEx](http://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/)'

Comment: ILMerge was already mentioned by two other answerers before you. Why do you recommend to obfuscate assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio on your project select publish. (Note: I'm using a .NET console application)

Use the following publish profile:
[image]

If you then click publish it should create a single .exe file everyone can run without having to install .NET framework.
[image]